# Does the Sony PS4 Controller (Dualshock/DS4) work via USB on a Mac?

Tags: ps4, controllers, macos

Simple question that I cannot find the simple answer to anywhere on the web.

Does the Sony PS4 controller work ***via USB*** with a Mac computer? Without any configuration? Just by plugging it in?

Any Mac I plug this controller into, it doesn't even recognize it. Does not light up. I have tried multiple micro-USB cables, different Macs, different Mac OS versions (!), and still nothing. It works fine on my Windows PC and PS4, so I know the controller is working properly.

A YES or NO would be good, with an explanation thereafter as to why. USB power issue? Driver issue? What is it? Why does this work on Windows just by plugging it in?

Note I am fully aware of the wireless/bluetooth capabilities. Please do not reference these as there are hundreds of setups guides and clear answers regarding wireless pairing of a PS4 controller to a Mac. **This question is specifically pointed at *wired* USB CONNECTIVITY.**

Comment: May I ask if there's a reason you don't want to use bluetooth?

Comment: It works, tested with DS4 models CUH-ZCT1U and CUH-ZCT2U on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 using https://gamepad-tester.com in Chrome.